# Is there a way to limit the size of an element list in a Page Object?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I am working on an automated test and I am able to get a list of elements that I need on a page using the following:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace iOSAutomation.PageObjects
{
    public class CCLMenu
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        // Menu element buttons
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "btn_MenuElement")]
        public IList<IWebElement> menuElement_buttons;


        // Constructor
        public CCLMenu(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
        }
    }
}
```

This gets a list of 166 elements though and takes a while to find them all and select one from the list to click. Here is a sample of the test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SelectCCLOptions()
{
    //...

    // THIS CURRENTLY GETS A LIST OF 166 ELEMENTS; TODO - Find a way to limit list size
    Debug.WriteLine("Array count: " + cclMenu.menuElement_buttons.Count);
    Assert.IsTrue(isElementPresent(driver, cclMenu.menuElement_buttons.ElementAt(1), 60), "Unable to find country menu element button on " + cclMenu.ToString());
    cclMenu.menuElement_buttons.ElementAt(1).Click();

    //...
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to limit the size of the list initialized in the Page Object because I only need about 30 of those elements and it would significantly speed up the test. I have tried initializing the list with the `new` keyword directly in the Page Object constructor with a specific capacity before calling `PageFactory.InitElements(...)` but it seems that a new list is instantiated each time the driver looks for the elements so this has no affect.

Any suggestions or is this even possible?

**Edit:** This is for an iOS phone application and we eventually want to be able to select a language at random at the beginning of our test run.

Comment: Before we get to the question you asked, there is the problem of (unless I'm misunderstanding) 166 duplicate ids on your page. If that's true you need to have a chat with your developers. http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

Comment: Append [CacheLookup] after the FindBys. This will cache the results and not search for elements again. If you got some kind off ajax calls on this element you might run into problems with caching. If you want a reduced set of results you will need to fine tune your locator strategy or get your devs to add unique ids as suggested above. Just an idea maybe use a xpath locator and look for button text which begin with a certain set of alphabets eg a,b,c,d...

Comment: @jibbs This is something that I actually asked them to do so that I could get the entire list of menu elements using a single ID in my page object.

Comment: @Grasshopper The only problem with caching the elements is that the list is reused for two other menus on this same page. It finds those elements when it navigates to that menu.

Comment: You can and should do this with classes not with ids. See my link above. I do exactly what you're talking about with classes. I am blown away that your developers had no problem creating duplicate ids. Whatever. The answer below is spot on. Though please note Royar's note. Same thing I said.

Comment: @jibbs After implementing the logic below I have removed the ids for those elements altogether so no more duplicates. You can rest easy. I will keep this in mind for the future as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're only interested in the second element.
I suggest creating the following property:

```
public IWebElement CountryMenu {
    get {
        return driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".btn_MenuElement:nth-of-type(1)"));
    }
}
```

":nth-of-type" is a css selector to get an element in a collection by its index.

Alternatively, you could create a method to retrieve an item by its index:

```
public IWebElement GetMenu(int index) {
    return driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(
        string.Format(".btn_MenuElement:nth-of-type({0})", index)
    ));
}
```

*note: I used class instead of id because it doesn't make sense to have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: I am using the XCUITest 'automationName' capability to support 10.1+ automation and CSS selectors are not currently supported with this. Should I try a similar approach using an XPath?

Comment: I implemented the same logic using an XPath and it worked. Also much faster than before. Thank you!